# Help me simplify this code (Python)

Tags: python, simplify, code-formatting

I'm a beginner in Python, teaching myself off of Google Code University. I had this problem as an exercise, and was able to solve it using the solution shown below:

```
# F. front_back
# Consider dividing a string into two halves.
# If the length is even, the front and back halves are the same length.
# If the length is odd, we'll say that the extra char goes in the front half.
# e.g. 'abcde', the front half is 'abc', the back half 'de'.
# Given 2 strings, a and b, return a string of the form
#  a-front + b-front + a-back + b-back
def front_back(a, b):
  if len(a) % 2 == 0:
    ad = len(a) / 2
    if len(b) % 2 == 0:
      bd = len(b) / 2
    else:
      bd = (len(b) / 2) + 1
  else:
    ad = (len(a) / 2) + 1
    if len(b) % 2 == 0: 
      bd = len(b) / 2
    else:
      bd = (len(b) / 2) + 1

  return a[:ad] + b[:bd] + a[ad:] + b[bd:]
```

This produces the correct output and solves the problem. However, I am duplicating the logic of whether to split a string evenly or add the odd number to the first half, and this seems redundant. There has to be a more efficient way of doing this. The same exact check and logic is being applied to a and b. Anyone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
def front_back(a, b):
    ad = (len(a) + 1) // 2
    bd = (len(b) + 1) // 2
    return a[:ad] + b[:bd] + a[ad:] + b[bd:]
```

Using `//` for division makes this code work in both Python 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: that's pretty, pretty much what I came up with

Comment: @Sven, can you explain us how does this works? ( particularly the `//`  operator )

Comment: @OscarRyz: `a // b` is the integer division of `a / b` -- it rounds down.

Comment: If `len(x)` is even, then `len(x)+1) // 2` is the same number. If `len(x)` is odd, then `(len(x)+1) // 2` is 1 more, as the code requires. So the same expression can be used for odd and even numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Well, put it in a separate function.

```
def front_back(string):
    offset = len(string) / 2
    if len(string) % 2 != 0:
        offset += 1
    return string[:offset], string[offset:]

def solution(a, b):
    front_a, back_a = front_back(a)
    front_b, back_b = front_back(b)
    return front_a + back_a + front_b + back_b
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're adding 1 to the length if it's odd, and 'odd' means that `len(a)%2 == 1`...

```
def front_back2(a, b):
    ad = (len(a) + len(a)%2) / 2
    bd = (len(b) + len(b)%2) / 2
    return a[:ad]+b[:bd]+a[ad:]+b[bd:]
```

Of course, you could even condense it to one line just for kicks (although, it's significantly less readable):

```
def front_back2(a, b):
    return a[:(len(a)+len(a)%2)/2]+b[:(len(b)+len(b)%2)/2]+a[(len(a)+len(a)%2)/2:]+b[(len(b)+len(b)%2)/2:]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the maximum index by using [`ceil`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.ceil)

```
In [1]: l = [1,2,3]
In [2]: import math
In [4]: math.ceil(len(l)/2.0)
Out[4]: 2.0
In [5]: l.append(4)
In [6]: math.ceil(len(l)/2.0)
Out[6]: 2.0
In [7]: l.append(5)
In [8]: math.ceil(len(l)/2.0)
Out[8]: 3.0
In [9]: l[0:3]
Out[9]: [1, 2, 3]
In [10]: l[3:]
Out[10]: [4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Mhh trying to understand [@Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947214/help-me-simplify-this-code-python/6947313#6947313) answer I got this:

```
len( s ) + 1 / 2
```

Will always give you the correct index.

So if we put that in a function:

```
def d( s ):
   return ( len(s) + 1 ) / 2
```

We can use it in the solution:

```
def front_back( a, b ): 
    return a[:d(a)] + b[:d(b)] + a[d(a):] + b[d(b):]
```

Ok, I got it now.

I'm not quite sure what's the difference between `/` and `//` though

Comment: That makes sense. I also still don't understand the difference between / and //

Comment: I commented on the difference between `/` and `//` below my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
from math import ceil

def front_back(a, b):
    divide = lambda s: int(ceil(len(s) / 2.0)) # or lambda s: (len(s) + 1) // 2
    a_divide, b_divide = divide(a), divide(b)
    return a[:a_divide] + b[:b_divide] + a[a_divide:] + b[b_divide:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine:

```
def front_back( a, b ) :
    return of(a)[0] + of(b)[0] + of(a)[1] + of(b)[1]

def of( s ):
   index = len( s ) / 2 + ( 1 if len( s ) % 2 == 1 else 0 )
   return ( s[ : index ] , s[ index : ] )


print front_back('abcde','hola')
```

Prints:

```
abchodela
```